# Access this in a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass a reference to the class through to a method so I can access a var:

I have tried:

```
p.id = 1;
p._initEvents = function(){
    $('#file-form').on('valid.fndtn.abide', this.save.bind(this));
};


p.save = function(){
   console.log(this.id);
}
```

Which just passes a reference to the file form.

I have also tried:

```
var self = this;
p._initEvents = function(){
    $('#file-form').on('valid.fndtn.abide', this.save.bind(self));
}


p.save = function(){
   console.log(self.id);
}
```

Which produces undefined.

I know this.id is set correctly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try: p.save = function( elem ){
   console.log(elem.id);
}

Comment: You can even store the reference to this in a variable in `on` callback...

Comment: Can someone tell me what's the role of `bind(this)` here..?

Comment: @panthro: And how are you calling `p._initEvents`?

Comment: @ Jonas Grumann id is a var not an element

Comment: @Matt this._initEvents();

Comment: @TilwinJoy: See [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It allows you to chose the value of `this` within the function.

Comment: @Matt im quite sure, il run another test.

Comment: @panthro: Then what you've tried first should work. Are you sure thats the code you're using?

Comment: @Matt: The reason it's not working is because `this` in the `.on` function callback doesn't refer to `p`.

Comment: @ColinDeClue: that is irrelevant in this case, because he's forcing the value of `this` inside the callback using `bind()`.

Comment: @Matt: That's not working. jQuery is forcing `this` to refer to `#file-form`.

Comment: @ColinDeClue (& cc panthro): The code you're using [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/B9jWy/). Can you create your own jsFiddle/ jsBin to show the problem?

Comment: @Matt: Oh yeah I went and tested it myself. I was trusting him that it was referring to `#file-form` somehow. My guess is he had a different version earlier (with a `function() { p.save.bind(this)();}` or something)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to access `p` in `p.save`?

Here's an option:

```
p.id = 1;
p._initEvents = function(){
    $('#file-form').on('valid.fndtn.abide', this.save.bind(p));
};


p.save = function(){
   console.log(this.id);
}
```